# web интерфейс приложения

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Написал программу на питоне которая решает простые задачи по генетике. Хотелось бы обеспечить доступ к этой программе с любого устройства из любого места. Интерфейс на html/css написать могу. Скажите, что будет той прослойкой, которая будет пересылать текст с текстовых полей в программу и выводить то, что выводит программа.

Comment: Если программа интерактивная, то [можно вебсокеты использовать чтобы данные с клиента вашей программе посылать и обратно (ваша программа на место скрипта с line.upper() посещается)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729467/4279).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я для таких вещей использую [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html). Это очень простой веб-сервер. Из-за своей простоты он редко используется: мало функциональности.

Обратная сторона этого – его легко усвоить. По ссылке выше есть hello world, которого будет достаточно для описанной задачи.

Если есть желание сделать что-то покруче – рекомендую [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Он так же прост при базовом использовании, но позволяет делать куда более крутые и сложные штуки.

Comment: Если программа интерактивная, то bottle.py может быть недостаточно. socket.io на клиенте и `flask-socketio` на сервере могут быть более удобными.

Comment: Согласен, такой вариант гибче, но сложнее для новичка.Я бы начал с максимально простого, но рабочего варианта и усложнял его, если надо.

Comment: Дело не в гибкости, а в том будет вообще работать или нет. Например, если нужно произвести деление `1/2`, то результат `0.5` (float division) он не просто *"гибче"* —это совсем другой результат, который отличается от (более простого) `1//2 == 0` целочисленного деления. Да, float arithmetic может быть более сложной для новичка чем арифметика с целыми числами, но если нам нужен ответ `0.5`, а не `0` то необходимо использовать именно float division. Из вопроса, не ясно что из себя представляет программа (как она с внешним миром общается), поэтому разные варианты могут подходить.

Comment: Решил все же изучить Flask

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется гораздо проще переписать вычисления на JavaScript. 
 Но если очень хочется использовать именно пайтон - то можно попробовать сделать с его помощью бэкэнд сайта. Детали тут:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html
либо по запросу в гугл "python as a web server". 
 В таком случае не нужна будет никакая прослойка. Хотя дописать/чуть чуть переписать программу, скорее всего, всё-таки нужно будет.